# "Missing argument for parameter 'for' in call"

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta6

Whilst coding in swift3 I wanted to use custom protocols and generics for reusing collection view cells. I know that this is the standard way of reusing cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TacoCell", for: indexPath) as? TacoCell {

        cell.configureCell(taco: ds.tacoArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

But everytime I try to do this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as TacoCell
    cell.configureCell(taco: ds.tacoArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

The compiler complains I have a "Missing argument for parameter 'for' in call"... The parameter in this case is "forIndexPath"

FYI...

I have custom extensions for reusing cells and loading nibs. Code is as follows:

ReusableView class

```
import UIKit

protocol ReusableView: class  { }

extension ReusableView where Self: UIView {

    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return String.init(describing: self)
    }
}
```

NibLoadableView class

```
import UIKit

protocol NibLoadableView: class { }

extension NibLoadableView where Self: UIView {

    static var nibName: String {
        return String.init(describing: self)
    }
}
```

This is my extension for the UICollectionView

```
import UIKit

extension UICollectionView {
    func register<T: UICollectionViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: ReusableView, T: NibLoadableView {

    let nib = UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: nil)
    register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier)
}


func dequeueReusableCell<T: UICollectionViewCell>(forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> T where T: ReusableView {

    guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? T else {
        fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.reuseIdentifier)")
    }

    return cell
    }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell: ReusableView { }
```

Comment: Could you provide a link for the description of `dequeueReusableCell` that uses (only) `forIndexPath`? Also, have you tried replacing `forIndexPath` with `for`?

Comment: Sorry @Evert... I made an extension of the UICollectionView and I am using  my"overrided" `dequeueReusableCell` method which has the argument `forIndexPath`. My assumption was since it was accepted as an extension, I could use it to reuse my cells. I included the extension code above as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a little bit of Swift 2.2 code alongside your Swift 3.0 code, and the compiler is getting confused when it tries to pick a method to call because nothing quite matches.

Your `cellForItemAt` method calls your own `dequeueReusableCell()` extension method with the `IndexPath` from the collection view. However, the extension method you wrote expects to receive an `NSIndexPath`, which is a subtly different thing.

Amend your extension method to this and the problem should clear up:

```
func dequeueReusableCell<T: UICollectionViewCell>(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> T where T: ReusableView {
```

Comment: Thank you @TwoStraws! That seemed to get it going